# Do fixtures trigger model callbacks?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fixtures

Say I have a User model with the following code in User.rb:

```
before_create :create_dependencies
after_create :build_inbox
```

And I also have a users.yml file with a bunch of user fixtures defined in it.

When I run rake db:fixtures:load, it doesn't appear to trigger the callbacks.

1. Is this how it is expected to work? If so, why did they design it this way?
2. Is there a way to force the triggering of the callbacks when loading fixtures?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

> Is this how it is expected to work? If
>   so, why did they design it this way?

Yes, fixtures do not use callbacks. I'm assuming this is for performance reasons. It is quicker to load the data straight into the database without instantiating the model.

> Is there a way to force the triggering
>   of the callbacks when loading
>   fixtures?

Not that I know of. You have a couple options. One is to build your fixtures as if the callbacks were already triggered. That is, manually create the data that the callbacks would. For example, if you have a callback which hashes a user's password you would need to hash the password manually and then store that hash in the fixture.

The second solution (and highly recommended!) is to use factories. Factories do trigger callbacks and allow you to use virtual attributes, etc. This is because they do instantiate the model each time. One popular gem is [Factory Girl](http://thoughtbot.com/projects/factory_girl). Another one to try is [Machinist](http://github.com/notahat/machinist/tree/master). I have also created a [Railscasts episode](http://railscasts.com/episodes/158-factories-not-fixtures) on the topic.

Comment: +1 to factory girl. Switched to it abot 2 months ago, and I never looked back.

Comment: +1 because Factory Girl is so amazing... take the hour to learn it, you'll make up for your lost time very quickly.

Comment: You can also do something like this where user is your fixture. `user._run_create_callbacks`

Answer (score 3):

I have this problem as well.  Our app calculates some totals before_save so it doesn't have to be done on the fly.  Makes reporting faster and cuts out a few joins on certain reports.

In the tests for those objects we manually run the callbacks like this:

```
before do
  order.perform_callbacks
end
```

This works out well because it doesn't run all the time so other tests don't suffer.

We are using minitest and fixtures btw.

Comment: Where does this code live?  Top of the fixture?  What is order?

Comment: Hi hellion.  The code lives at the top of my test file in a before stmt because for me in this case I need it for every test in this file.  If you only need to ensure the callbacks run for 1 test you can just put the .perform_callbacks in that particular test though.

Comment: What is `order`, a class, an instance? It's strange that I can't find `perform_callbacks` documented anywhere.