# Rails - after_create method not calling while using ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures to create records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, fixtures

In my project, create seed data using ActiveRecord::FixtureSet.create_fixtures i.e through .yml for eg below is one of of my seed file of a model say customer.yml,

```
ashblood:
  id: 1
  name: The American Society of Hematology
  contact: 
  email: 
  symbol: ashblood
```

When I run rake scimed:db:seed, the above sample data gets created as a record in customer table . But once this is created I want to call a method in Customer model on after_create where I need to update a data dynamically which is not working. Can anyone help around to find a way for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

See for more options [Do fixtures trigger model callbacks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1223101/do-fixtures-trigger-model-callbacks), but without changing anything else; you can run the create callbacks in a test using `_run_create_callbacks`:

```
ashblood = customers(:ashblood)
ashblood._run_create_callbacks
```